# Iterating through the array values using handlebars #each loop

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

I have two arrays named firstnames and lastnames. The values these two arrays hold are as follows:-

```
firstnames =[ 'A', 'B', 'C','D','E' ]
lastnames =['a','b','c','d','e']
```

I am rendering these two arrays to my webpage in the following manner:-

```
res.render('sample',{firstnames:firstnames,lastnames:lastnames})
```

Using the #each loop-helper in handlebars, I was able to display the names on the webpage in such a way that all the firstnames appear first followed by all the lastnames by making use of this :-

```
  {{#each firstname}}
  <h1>{{this}}</h1>
    {{/each}}
    
    {{#each lastname}}
   <h1>{{this}}</h1>
    {{/each}}
```

And the output was some thing like:-

```
A 
B
C
D
E
a
b
c
d
e
```

But, how can I able to display the data in such a way that, each firstname must be followed by the each lastname. Like that of below:-

```
A
a
B
b
C
c
D
d
E
e
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

This can be done using the [Handlebar's lookup helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) using either the [`../` path](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths) or [`@root` data variable](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html#data) syntax in combination with the [`@key` data variable](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html#data). Using either `../` or `@root` is necessary because `#each` creates a new context. In other words, each object in `firstnames` would be the new context, so it is necessary to get back to the root scope, because that is where `lastnames` is located.

```js
{{#each firstnames}}
    <h1>{{this}}</h1>
    <h1>{{lookup @root.lastnames @key}}</h1>
    // OR
    <h1>{{lookup ../lastnames @key}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```

### Snippet/Example

```js
var data = {
  firstnames: [ 'A', 'B', 'C','D','E' ],
  lastnames: ['a','b','c','d','e']
};

var source = $('#entry-template').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source)(data);

$('body').html(template)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each firstnames}}
    <h1>{{this}}</h1>
    <h1>{{lookup ../lastnames @key}}</h1>
{{/each}} 
</script>
```